# Javafx while selecting text using mouse in webview the selecting word is split or overlap

Tags: javafx-2

I want to select the text in webview while i am  selecting text content using mouse in webview, the selected text word is split or the mouse selecting first word alignment overlap. how to solve this issue.

Just i have load a simple html file in javafx weview component. while select the text in webview the word is split or overlapping. i am not use any JavaScript.

You can find the doubt in the following link:
[enter link description here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/94297692@N04/8581160685/)

Answer (score 0):

WebView not correctly rendering selection areas is a known issue in JavaFX 2.2:

- [RT-18883 Google docs editing issues](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18883)
- [RT-11239 Add draw glyph type support to Prism graphics](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-11239)

Comment: ok, When it will be resolve ?, if have you know any other component like this ?

Comment: I do not know the answer to either of those follow up questions.